# GoLang calling a function using gin without passing gin.Context

Tags: go, go-gin

I've come across a scenario where

```
func main (c *gin.Context){
    if err := g.Bind(&data); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
            helper.TraceLog(err)
            helper.Fail(c, helper.INPUT_PARAMS_ERROR, "", err)
            return
    }
}

func Fail(c *gin.Context, errorCode string, result string, message interface{}) {
    response := Response{}
    response.Code = errorCode
    response.Result = message
    response.Message = result

    json.Marshal(response)
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, response)
}
```

Is it possible that I do not have to pass gin to Fail func? I've tried every solution I can think of and nothing works.

The reason I'm doing this is to make the code looks more simple and clean.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
    func main (c *gin.Context){
        if err := g.Bind(&data); err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
                helper.TraceLog(err)
                helper.Fail(helper.INPUT_PARAMS_ERROR, "", err)
                return
        }
    }

    func Fail(errorCode string, result string, message interface{}) {
        var c *gin.Context

        response := Response{}
        response.Code = errorCode
        response.Result = message
        response.Message = result

        json.Marshal(response)
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, response)
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide helper definition?

Comment: @getupandgo helper.INPUT_PARAMS_ERROR is a const variable (error code)

Comment: as far as I understood, you want to handle validation errors via Fail() function? Did you consider using middleware for this purpose like in [this](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/274#issuecomment-104472296) thread? As for me, error handling middleware is the cleanest approach to error handling in controllers

Comment: To clarify: using this approach, your controller will look like [this](https://gist.github.com/getupandgo/7b5f1da9a97d946d4ef99a45cdc7db9c), and error handling middleware will parse, format and send response with error

Comment: Thanks for your answer. while scrolling through the links you posted, I've found that instead of the solution you provided , the c.JSON(http.statuscode, fail()) fit my needs as I've quite a few possible errors to return and this way is the best approach for me.

Thank you once again , you helped a ton !